# IO Exception in Java Packager: Exec failed with code 2 command

Tags: java, javapackager

I want to create executable bundle for windows from java's jar application using the `javapackager` but facing issues.

**Running cmd command**

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Final -srcdir . -srcfiles Hello.jar -appclass sample.Main
```

**Exception**

```
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Creating app bundle: Main in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Java Packager\packages\bundles
Result application bundle: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Java Packager\packages\bundles
java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[C:\Program Files (x86)\InnoSetup6\iscc.exe, 
/oC:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Java Packager\packages\bundles, 
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler6308867820319632690\images\win-exe.image\Main.iss] in 
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler6308867820319632690\images\win-exe.image
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:697)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:366)
    at com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.execute(WinExeBundler.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.Main.main(Main.java:476)
Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.
```

Comment: Did you check if this happens when using InnoSetup5? The new version might not be compatible.

Comment: @FibreFoX thanks, its the compatibility issues with the InnoSetup6 and java packager, downgrade the version of InnoSetup and it fixed the issue.